# Is there a way to have a views filter value be determined by PHP?

Tags: 7, views

I need to search for fields that are equal to the value of a visitor cookie. How do I get $_COOKIE[somecookie] as the criterion value in the views filter? (I know that I could use views_php to grab all the records and filter out after the fact but that's a lot of records and would be far too slow.)

It would be preferable to be able to do this without writing a custom module. It seems like this would be a common request by admins so I feel I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup the page to use a `contextual filter` per `field` you want to be searchable. Then for the contextual filter set it to look for the value `provided by the URL`. Then select `PHP Code` for `WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL`.

In that PHP blob supply code that pulls the field argument from `$_COOKIE`, if any or return `NULL`.

Comment: Once I get the rep points I'll come back and upvote as well.